# android phonegap plugin for printing with send2printer

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, network-printers

I made a simple example using the android plugin for printplugin
Here the plugin:
https://github.com/EionRobb/phonegap-print-plugins/tree/master/Android

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Prueba de Impresion</title>
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"    type="text/css">
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="phonegap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="printplugin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function imprime(){
    var html = document.getElementById("printHTML").innerHTML;

    window.plugins.printPlugin.print(html,
            function(result) {
                alert("print ok");
            }, 
            function(result) {
                if (!result.available){
                    alert("no printing available");
                }
                else{
                    //Localised error description
                    alert(result.error);
                }
            }

        );
    }
</script>

<div data-role="page" id="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Prueba de Impresion</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <button data-icon="gear" onClick="imprime();">Imprimir</button>
  Contenido</div>
   <div id="printHTML">

          <div style="color: red;">
              <p>Either the well was very deep, or she fell very slowly, for she had    plenty of time as she went down to look about her and to wonder what was  going to happen next. First, she tried to look down and make out what  she was coming to, but it was too dark to see anything; then she  looked at the sides of the well, and noticed that they were filled with  cupboards and book-shelves; here and there she saw maps and pictures  hung upon pegs. She took down a jar from one of the shelves as  she passed; it was labelled 'ORANGE MARMALADE', but to her great  disappointment it was empty: she did not like to drop the jar for fear  of killing somebody, so managed to put it into one of the cupboards as  she fell past it.</p>
          </div>

          <div style="color: green; page-break-before:always;">
              <p>In the Propontis, as far as I can learn, none of that peculiar substance called BRIT is to be found, the aliment of the right whale. But I have every reason to believe that the food of the sperm whale&mdash;squid or cuttle-fish&mdash;lurks at the bottom of that sea, because large creatures, but by no means the largest of that sort, have been found at its surface. If, then, you properly put these statements together, and reason upon them a bit, you will clearly perceive that, according to all human reasoning, Procopius's sea-monster, that for half a century stove the ships of a Roman Emperor, must in all probability have been a sperm whale.</p>                
          </div>


          <div style="color: blue; page-break-before:always;">
              <p>They were not their families, nor their wives, nor their servants; the relationship was peculiar, and so unlike anything known to us that it is most difficult to describe.  All property among the green Martians is owned in common by the community, except the personal weapons, ornaments and sleeping silks and furs of the individuals.  These alone can one claim undisputed right to, nor may he accumulate more of these than are required for his actual needs.  The surplus he holds merely as custodian, and it is passed on to the younger members of the community as necessity demands.</p>

      </div>

      </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Pie</h4>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the application runs and displays the message: no printing available, and in logcat I see the following message:
Error: Status=undefined Message=Class not found at file:///android_asset/www/phonegap.js:473

I have installed 1.4.4 send2printer

if someone could tell me I'm doing wrong
Thanks to all in advance

Comment: Did you add the plugin to your plugins/config file? What does line 473 of phonegap.js say?

Comment: yes, my config.xml is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugins>
   <plugin name="PrintPlugin"  value="com.prueba.impresion.PrintPlugin"/>
</plugins>      and the error message is Class not found service=PrintPlugin action=print

Comment: Are you also including the printPlugin .java file in a new package called com.preueba.impression.PrintPlugin? It sounds like it is just a configuration/install issue with the plugin.

Comment: yes, the problem is to install the plugin but something is wrong, I have included the file PrintPlugin.java

Comment: What version of Cordova is this?

Comment: I tested with version 2.7 and 0.95 phonegap, I have included plugins.xml and config.xml to avoid problems with the version.